# zoho crm api insert/update Leads

Tags: xml, api, crm, zoho

I'm trying to update and insert Leads using the Zoho CRM API and I sometimes get the following error:

```
<response><error><code>4600</code><message>Unable to process your request. Please verify if the     name and value is appropriate for the "xmlData" parameter.</message></error></response>
```

My problem is that sometimes everything works fine and sometimes I get this error, but I'm struggling to see any difference between 'good' XML and 'bad' XML. I'm enclosing all values in CDATA tags.

Answer (score 1):

as the response 4600 indicates that the xml was not in readable form, you should check your xml values closely and see if any special character is causing the issue. In my case, apostrophe was breaking the xml.

Answer (score 1):

the standard xml format for zoho api is following, Please update your xml format according to this.

```
$xmlData=
<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="Lead Source">Web Download</FL>
<FL val="Company">Your Company</FL>
<FL val="First Name">Hannah</FL>
<FL val="Last Name">Smith</FL>
<FL val="Email">testing@testing.com</FL>
<FL val="Title">Manager</FL>
<FL val="Phone">1234567890</FL>
<FL val="Home Phone">0987654321</FL>
<FL val="Other Phone">1212211212</FL>
<FL val="Fax">02927272626</FL>
<FL val="Mobile">292827622</FL>
</row>
</Leads>
```

Comment: BTW, the new format is JSON instead of XML, and the newer API has a painful oAuth hurdle to get through that is not very well documented. I have created [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61961302/105539) that explains this process.